# HQL extracting only one result out of multiple results

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate, hql

I am running **HQL** query to get results from **MS SQL Server**. The hibernate generated SQL gives the correct output(2 results for eg,) but Hibernate only extracts one result. Even in the stack trace it shows that the query returned one result. I have tried using order by desc and asc but it always gets the one with the lowest ID value. I have looked at my model but there seems to be no fault with it.

I am using `createquery("my query").list()` method. Did someone encountered the same issue?

`createquery("from Analysis a where a.sample = *someNumber* ").list()`

The HQL generated SQL gives correct results when I run this on the database

`select
        analysis0_.idAnalysis as idAnalys1_5_,
        analysis0_.changes_timestamp as changes_2_5_,
        analysis0_.Analysis_Done_Date as Analysis3_5_,
        analysis0_.Analysis_Remarks as Analysis4_5_,
        analysis0_.Sample_idSample as Sample_i5_5_,
        analysis0_.Analysis_Start_Date as Analysis6_5_,
        analysis0_.Analysis_Status as Analysis7_5_ 
    from
        Re_at_AIM_User.analysis analysis0_ 
    where
        analysis0_.Sample_idSample=*someNumber*`

public class Analysis implements Serializable {

```
private static final long serialVersionUID = -1216945678610624994L;

@Column(name = "changes_timestamp", columnDefinition = "datetime")
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
private Date changesTimestamp;


@Column(name = "Analysis_Done_Date", columnDefinition = "datetime")
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
private Date doneDate;

@Id
@Column(name = "idAnalysis", columnDefinition = "bigint")
private Integer id;

@Column(name = "Analysis_Remarks")
private String remarks;

@Column(name = "Analysis_Start_Date", columnDefinition = "datetime")
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
private Date startDate;

@Column(name = "Analysis_Status")
private String status;

@ManyToOne()
@JoinColumn(name = "Sample_idSample")
private Sample sample;

public Analysis() {
}

public Date getChangesTimestamp() {
    return changesTimestamp;
}



public Date getDoneDate() {
    return doneDate;
}

public Integer getId() {
    return id;
}


public String getRemarks() {
    return remarks;
}

public Date getStartDate() {
    return startDate;
}

public String getStatus() {
    return status;
}

public void setChangesTimestamp(Date changesTimestamp) {
    this.changesTimestamp = changesTimestamp;
}



public void setDoneDate(Date doneDate) {
    this.doneDate = doneDate;
}

public void setId(Integer idAnalysis) {
    this.id = idAnalysis;
}

public void setRemarks(String remarks) {
    this.remarks = remarks;
}

public void setStartDate(Date startDate) {
    this.startDate = startDate;
}

public void setStatus(String status) {
    this.status = status;
}

public Sample getSample() {
    return sample;
}

public void setSample(Sample sample) {
    this.sample = sample;
}
```

}

Comment: Can you please share the query you are using to get the data?

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate method `list()` [is deprecated](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/javadocs/org/hibernate/Query.html#list--).

Use [`getResultList()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/Query.html#getResultList--) instead.

Answer (score 0):

It was a terrible mistake. Was using the test database instead. Officially the most stupid first question. Apologies for the bother.